# newrelic - Unable to login to new relic service bound to an app on bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, newrelic, websphere-liberty

Unable to login to a newrelic service bound to a bluemix app, returns a Login Failed ! message on the browser

The bluemix app is hooked up to a SSO service, I was able to login to same newrelic instance 2 days ago, now for some reason it stopped working.

Is there a way to get this working without deleting this instance of newrelic ?

[image: login error]

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you figure out what was going on here?

Comment: yea. I had to delete the NewRelic service and add a new one to get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be encountering an issue with Bluemix restarting services to address a newly identified security vulnerability. See the status updates for individual services here: https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/maint151023/